# How to get Maximum length of the field using Restlet in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I created custom field in Netsuite account and set Maximum Length : 10.

when i tried to get that maximum length of the field via restlet using below code

**field_details['maxLength'] = field.maxLength;**( also tried field.maxLength() )

But it didn't work.

Any idea how to get maxLength value of field using Restlet ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the nlobjField (NS field object) doesn't have a method to get the Max Length.